# Multiplos usuários de compartilhamento ao instalar o SQL Server

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, windows, sql-server-express

Instalei recentemente o *SQL Server Express 2016* na minha máquina com *Windows 10*.

Depois de um tempo percebi que no menu "*Compartilhar com*" do Windows apareceram **13 entradas novas** no formato *SQLEXPRESS**NN***, onde **NN** varia de 01 até 13.

A imagem ilustra melhor:

[image: As novas opções misteriosas do menu Compartilhar com]

Alguém sabe me dizer o que isso significa? No gerenciamento de usuários do Windows não encontrei nada a respeito.

Observação importante: **não adicionei nenhum usuário** no *SQL Server*, além do **sa** criado na instalação.

Comment: Emerson, seria interessante incluir mais detalhes na sua questão. Como dito pelo Jasar pode estar ligado a criação de novos usuários. Para confirmar [edit] sua pergunta incluindo o print dos usuários do sistema. É possível encontrá-los rodando no executar: `control userpasswords2` (Se possível censure seu usuário principal antes de postar :] )

Comment: Alterei a questão informando que nenhum usuário foi criado para o SQL Server.

Comment: Só pra confirmar, o que aparece ao rodar `control userpasswords2` ?

Comment: Infelizmente tive que formatar a máquina no final de semana, então não tenho como reproduzir o resultado de `control userpasswords2`

Comment: Difícil saber então o que causou esse problema :\ pesquisei no google e não achei nada do tipo... Tente instalar o SQL Server Express novamente e veja se acontece novamente para podermos descobrir o que pode ser isso :)

Answer (score 0):

Para cada usuário q vc cria dentro do sql server ele deve ta criando um correspondente para o Windows para que este usuário possa se conectar externamente.
verifique quantos usuários vc tem no seu banco.

Comment: Jasar, não adicionei nenhum usuário no SQL Server além do **sa** criado na instalação.